# Gulp TypeError: glob pattern string required. В чём проблема?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Я следую по этой статье https://www.8host.com/blog/nachalo-raboty-s-gulp-js/ , чтобы настроить *gulp.js* на убунту. Когда я ввожу "gulp styles" происходит ошибка `TypeError: glob pattern string require`. Что я делаю не так?

Мой *gulpfile.js*

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
rename = require('gulp-rename')

gulp.task('styles', function() {
   return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переменные необходимо закрывать, посмотрите на строку rename, возможно проблема в этом. И вот еще: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629296/gulp-js-typeerror-glob-pattern-string-required

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строку и запустить

    `.pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))`.

В [документации плагина gulp-ruby-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass) опции style нет, может быть из-за этого ошибка, урок по которому вы делаете годичной давности, поэтому вполне вероятно, что ее могли убрать.